# Adding Day of the Week and Keeping the date

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I am aware of the function to get the "Day of the Week" from a date value.  Is it possible to get the "Day of the Week" and keep the date in the same column?

Example Record: January 20, 2017

Desired Output: Friday, January 20, 2017

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: That's normally the sort of thing I'd do in whichever code *reads* the values from the database, not the database itself. Any reason you want to do it in SQL?

Comment: you want to update your column with new values?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Jon Skeet, I was just trying to find a solution during a select statement.  Since their are several date columns in this table, this was a request to format the date during a select.  I was trying to see if their was a format to use.  But, I am sensing that the easiest way is to select the data in its original format and then change the column format in Excel.

Comment: Karthik Ganesan, I dont want to update the column with new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main question is: How is the value stored?

Is it a *real* `DATE` or `DATETIME` (there are more) column or do you store this value as string?

### appropriate type

If this value is stored in an appropriately typed column, the internal value **is not the value you see**. What you see is a textual represenation of the interally stored binary value and depends on language and culture settings.

### string type

If this value is stored as the text you show us, I would really push it to change this. **Culture specific** formats are bad, but culture specific **and language dependant** formats are coming directly out of hell...

As Jon Skeet told you in his comment, such formattin issues are better done within your presentaion layer.

### Facit

- Never **store** such a date format
- Use the proper type to store date and time values
- Do formatting *on-the-fly* when you read this value (best in your calling application)
- If you need this to be done in SQL (reporting?) you'll need `CONVERT` with the appropriate format code (107?) and concatenate this with the day's name.

Comment: Shnugo, these are actually stored as DATETIME.  Like I told Jon Skeet, I am sensing this could be a complex issue on a select statement so it seems like the easiest way is to grab the data amd change the column format in excel

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure

but looks like you are looking for something like this

```
DECLARE @dummyDate VARCHAR(50) = 'January 20, 2017'

SET @dummyDate =  (SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(dw,@dummyDate ),','+@dummyDate ))
SELECT @dummyDate
```

example here 
http://rextester.com/WLMU29292

Comment: I really hope, that the OP does not store these date values in a culture and language dependant string format. This solution would not work on a system with different settings... With dates one should never rely on implicit conversions... Further more `CONCAT` was not available in SS2008, If the OP would use SS2012 he should rather use `FORMAT()`...

Comment: I completely agree... But I have no idea what how it is being saved and what needs to be done with it